# Value of miDebugger path is invalid in VS code while executing c program

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Getting continuous error "unable to start debugging. The value of `miDebuggerPath` is invalid". while running a c program in VS Code

Here is launch.json file

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gcc",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is tasks.json

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to change the path of compiler but it's not working.

Comment: Please don't tag multiple different languages. Tagging multiple different languages is mostly only valid when doing comparisons between the languages.

Comment: Also please take some time read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: As for your problem: The `tasks.json` file seems to indicate a POSIX environment (Linux or macOS or similar), while the `launch.json` uses a Windows path for the debugger. What system are you on?

Comment: Windows 11   version 21H2

Comment: And you're running VSCode *in* Windows? Not in e.g. WSL? Is `C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe` a valid path on your system? What happens if you replace it with e.g. `/usr/bin/gdb`? You *have* installed `gdb`?

Comment: yes i'm running VS code in windows. I have installed the compiler as their instructions on the vs official site. https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: Reading [this official guide for VSCode + MinGW (MSYS2)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) it says yo use `"miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe"`

Comment: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin this is path i use currently, none of them is working.

Comment: Not in the `launch.json` you show us. And why not simply find the `gdb.exe` file on your system and use that path? That would probably have been *much* quicker than the about 40 minutes you spent here waiting for an answer.

Comment: okey I'll do that